# grep using a file

Tags: text-processing, command-line, grep

I have 2 files and I want to find the difference and output only what is not inside ex2

If use `grep -Ff ex2.txt ex1.txt`, it shows me  `a b c d`, if I use the same command with `-v` there is not output. Why with does the first command also output `d`?

What would be the easiest way to do this? Is grep suitable for this? Maybe diff maybe a script that would read each line and output if it's there or not?

```
cat ex1.txt
a
b
c
d

cat ex2.txt
a
b
c
```

Edit---my output shows up like this:

```
cat ex2.txt
a
b
c

cat ex1.txt
a
b
c
d

grep -vf ex2.txt ex1.txt

grep -f ex2.txt ex1.txt
a
b
c
d
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment, by chance? What have you tried so far? Have you actually tried the "diff" command?

Comment: No its not I just want to understand why you also see d on the output if it is supposed to grep whatever is on that file. I tried diff i want to know if you can have the same results with grep, too.

Comment: Possibly `ex2.txt` also contains an empty line which would tell grep to look for the empty string and the empty string can be found in any line.

Comment: I added a solution which I think might help you learn from this... though, I maintain it's probably not the "right" way to do it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas looks like you're right. Have a look at the edited question. There's a blank line at the end of `ex1`.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is not really the right tool for the job here, but a quick look at the `grep manpage` should help (please note that `grep` will vary semi-wildly between distributions, as some may use GNU by default and others may use something else).

- -F ... Fixed Strings (separated by newlines) - (Category: matcher selection)
- -f ... Filename (Category: matching control)
- -v ... Invert match (Category: matching control)

So, you might imagine that something like `grep -Fvf ex2.txt ex1.txt` would work. However, **this is not a good solution**, as it requires you to already know something about the files prior to starting. There are better tools (like variants of `diff`) to give you more specific and more accurate differences between files and/or directories.

Edit: Fixed strings, not Fire strings (auto-corrupt be damned)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order of the files:

```
grep -v -f ex2.txt ex1.txt
> d
```

Comment: I believe the OP had "fixed" that prior to your answer, but was using "Ff" rather than "vf" ... I've posted a solution that uses "Fvf" instead. (though, this isn't really the right tool for the job, IMO)

Comment: Considering that the question is "how can I do it with grep", this is an answer that works. However, if it is just about finding the differences, I would use `diff` too.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce your error:

```
cat ex2.txt 
a
b
c

cat ex1.txt 
a
b
c
d

grep -vf ex2.txt ex1.txt 
d

grep -f ex2.txt ex1.txt 
a
b
c

grep -Ff ex2.txt ex1.txt 
a
b
c

grep -vFf ex2.txt ex1.txt 
d
```

---

```
grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.20

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.5 (jessie)
Release:    8.5
Codename:   jessie
```

**Edit** (on OS X with BSD grep):

```
cat ex2.txt 
a
b
c

cat ex1.txt 
a
b
c
d

grep -f ex2.txt ex1.txt 
a
b
c

grep -vf ex2.txt ex1.txt 
d

grep -Ff ex2.txt ex1.txt 
a
b
c

grep -v -Ff ex2.txt ex1.txt 
d
```

---

```
grep -V
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

Comment: Not all greps are built alike.

Comment: Strange,  I have different output. I edited my initial question with the output.

Comment: Indeed... OP hasn't given enough information for a "great" answer, here. But, YMMV depending on implementation (keeping in-mind that grep is often aliased and/or linked to one of the many others on a system, including egrep, fgrep, etc).

Comment: @RVT Oddly enough I just tried this on two different version of `grep` and I still get the desired output. Which one are you using that does not work?

Comment: @maulinglawns - I think you've mostly covered the bases, here. But, I'm just saying that "not all greps are built alike" and "OP hasn't given clear enough information" for a definitive answer... that is all. There are some systems that are "strange" out there (eg. Solaris). (And honestly, I'm still not convinced this isn't a homework assignment... LOL)